# How to aggregate same events in logstash into one new event

Tags: events, logging, aggregate, logstash

Lets say I get 10 login failures in about 60 seconds and I don't want to see all 10 events but only one that say there was 10 failed login attempts.

How (if it is possible) can I aggregate number of same events in logstash into one new event?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [metrics](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/metrics) filter.

It will allow you to flush every XX seconds (configurable) a metric event that can consists of various valuable metrics (e.g: percentiles of duration, rates, and count). You can use the filter and specify that you want an event to be flushed every 60 seconds, with the count of number of failed login attempts. The event will be flushed regardless if the count is higher or lower than 10, but you can query elastic search, whether manually or with Kibana, for only metric events where count is higher than 10.